# Google Autocomplete API to return list of associated houses based on UK postcode

Tags: javascript, google-api, autocomplete

Title pretty much summarizes it, I'm trying to return a list of houses that belong to a given postcode, such as if the user types

**G3 8UU**

for the sake of example, then the API returns all associated addresses - [functionality can be tested here](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/postcode-finder).

Can Google API do this? I've tried to set

```
types: ['geocode']
types: ['(address)']
```

but all I got in the dropdown list was street level and not all houses that have that post code, like

- 1 Long Road
- 2 Long Road
- 3 Long Road
- ...

Please advise, thank you.

Sorry, edit: [this is the code I use](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).